# Using Progressbar in xamarin fomrs

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, async-await

I have a xamarin form application in which there is option for creating a zip file. I use [SharpZipLib.Portable](https://github.com/ygrenier/SharpZipLib.Portable) plugin to create the zip file. I used the same sample explained [here](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples) for creating the zip file. I need to add progress bar to this application. I do this:

```
double FilesCount=0;
double CopyCount = 0;

    private void CreateZipFile()
    {
        string Folder = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).Path;
        FilesCount = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(Folder).Count();
        string ZipFilePath = Path.Combine(Folder, "File.zip");
        CreateSample(ZipFilePath, Folder);
    }

    public async void CreateSample(string outPathname, string folderName)
    {

        FileStream fsOut = File.Create(outPathname);
        ZipOutputStream zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(fsOut);

        zipStream.SetLevel(3);

        zipStream.Password = null; 

        int folderOffset = folderName.Length + (folderName.EndsWith("\\") ? 0 : 1);

        CompressFolderAsync(folderName, zipStream, folderOffset);

        zipStream.IsStreamOwner = true;
        zipStream.Close();

        await DisplayAlert("Creating Backup", "Creating backup is completed successfully. The buckup file is store in the following path: " + outPathname, "Ok");

    }

    private void CompressFolderAsync(string path, ZipOutputStream zipStream, int folderOffset)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);

        foreach (string filename in files)
        {

            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filename);

            string entryName = filename.Substring(folderOffset);
            entryName = ZipEntry.CleanName(entryName);
            ZipEntry newEntry = new ZipEntry(entryName);
            newEntry.DateTime = fi.LastWriteTime;
            newEntry.Size = fi.Length;
            zipStream.PutNextEntry(newEntry);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            using (FileStream streamReader = File.OpenRead(filename))
            {
                StreamUtils.Copy(streamReader, zipStream, buffer);
            }
            zipStream.CloseEntry();
        }

        CopyCount += 1;
        CreateBackupProgress.ProgressTo(CopyCount / FilesCount, 800, Easing.Linear);


        string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(path);

        foreach (string folder in folders)
        {
            CompressFolderAsync(folder, zipStream, folderOffset);
        }

    }
```

The problem is that the progress bar doesn't animated until the process finish. I tried to make the method async as follow:

```
await CreateBackupProgress.ProgressTo(CopyCount / FilesCount, 800, Easing.Linear);
```

But also not worked. I try using `Task.Run()` to make method works in background. This is the code:

```
    private async void CompressFolderAsync(string path, ZipOutputStream zipStream, int folderOffset)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);

        await Task.Run(() => {

            foreach (string filename in files)
        {

            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filename);

            string entryName = filename.Substring(folderOffset);
            entryName = ZipEntry.CleanName(entryName);
            ZipEntry newEntry = new ZipEntry(entryName);
            newEntry.DateTime = fi.LastWriteTime;
            newEntry.Size = fi.Length;
            zipStream.PutNextEntry(newEntry);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            using (FileStream streamReader = File.OpenRead(filename))
            {
                StreamUtils.Copy(streamReader, zipStream, buffer);
            }
            zipStream.CloseEntry();
        }


            CopyCount += 1;

            CreateBackupProgress.ProgressTo(CopyCount / FilesCount, 100, Easing.Linear);

        });

        string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(path);

        foreach (string folder in folders)
        {
            CompressFolderAsync(folder, zipStream, folderOffset);
        }

    }
```

But I get this error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: ZipOutputStream
>   was finished occurred

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: _"Is there a way for making progress bar work..."_ -- sure, there's a way. But asking "is there a way" is too broad. Asking for help debugging code without providing a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem is off-topic. That said, here's a hint: adding the word _"Async"_ to a method name does not actually make it async. It's only actually asynchronous if _you_ add code to the method to operate asynchronously (e.g. use `Task.Run()` to put long-running logic in a background task)

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Might be a cause of: a) You are blocking the UI thread by long running operation. b) You are updating the progress bar not from the UI thread. c) Your logic that updates the progress bar is incomplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem solved by using this:

```
double FilesCount = 0;
double CopyCount = 0;

    public async void CreateSample(string outPathname, string folderName)
    {

        FileStream fsOut = File.Create(outPathname);
        ZipOutputStream zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(fsOut);

        zipStream.SetLevel(3);

        zipStream.Password = null;

        int folderOffset = folderName.Length + (folderName.EndsWith("\\") ? 0 : 1);

        CreateBackupProgress.IsVisible = true;

        Task task1 = new Task(CheckProgressbar);
        task1.Start();

        Task task2 = new Task(() => CompressFolderAsync(folderName, zipStream, folderOffset));
        task2.Start();

        await task1;
        await task2;

        zipStream.IsStreamOwner = true;
        zipStream.Close();

        await DisplayAlert("Creating Backup", "Creating backup is completed successfully. The buckup file is store in the following path: " + outPathname, "Ok");

    }

    private void CompressFolderAsync(string path, ZipOutputStream zipStream, int folderOffset)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);

        foreach (string filename in files)
        {

            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filename);

            string entryName = filename.Substring(folderOffset);
            entryName = ZipEntry.CleanName(entryName);
            ZipEntry newEntry = new ZipEntry(entryName);
            newEntry.DateTime = fi.LastWriteTime;
            newEntry.Size = fi.Length;
            zipStream.PutNextEntry(newEntry);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            using (FileStream streamReader = File.OpenRead(filename))
            {
                StreamUtils.Copy(streamReader, zipStream, buffer);
            }
            zipStream.CloseEntry();
        }

        CopyCount += 1;

        string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(path);

        foreach (string folder in folders)
        {
            CompressFolderAsync(folder, zipStream, folderOffset);
        }

    }

    private async void CheckProgressbar()
    {

        while (CopyCount != FilesCount)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(100); }); 
            await CreateBackupProgress.ProgressTo(CopyCount / FilesCount, 100, Easing.Linear);

        }
        await CreateBackupProgress.ProgressTo(1, 100, Easing.Linear);

    }
```